# PHP Bayesian Classifier

Tags: php, python

I'm looking for a Naive Bayesian Classifier for PHP, ideally something equivalent to the Reverend Bayes version written in Python. Does anyone know of such a library?

Basically I need to be able to train it with a set of labels and words i.e. GOOD = okay, happy, fun; BAD = wrong, rubbish, awful etc and then pass it a string value and have it return a best guess. Reverend does this perfectly but unfortunately the app it now has to be used in is not Python based and making a bridge between the two isn't doable.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated as most of the classes I've found seem to be medically orientated with just a few cases or set-up for spam filtering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-bayes1/) looks like a nice set of tutorials on the subject. A similar question has been asked [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310478/implementing-bayesian-classifier-in-php) and the only real answer pointed to the same resource.

Bayesian filtering is a general approach. Even if examples you find are medical, the techniques are pretty much the same and can be applied anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, I'd seen the link before but just couldn't work out how it maps into what I'm trying to achieve. I'll have another look though.